# Joining two tables and selecting a relating value from the first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables (simplified views):

**Product**
ProductId (PK)
Name
VariableProduct (Bit)

**ProductVariation**
ProductVariationId (PK)
Name
ProductId (FK)

**ProductImage**
ProductImageId (PK)
ImageUrl
ProductId (FK)
ProductVariationId (FK) NULLABLE

I need to join the two tables to output a list of "ProductSearch" which is a simplified view model.

A Product can have a main image, a variation can have its own variation image.

In the join, I would like to specify the parent image for the variable product, if the variation image value is null.

The code I have is as follows:

```html
            //Single products first
            var products = await _context.Product.Where(p => p.Enabled == true && p.VariableProduct == false)
            .Include(e => e.ProductImages.Where(p => p.IsDefault == true && p.ProductVariationId == null))
            .Select(p => new ProductSearch()
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                ProductVariationId = null,
                Name = p.Name,
                ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl.FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl
            }).ToListAsync();

            //Variables
            var productVariables = await _context.ProductVariation
            .Include(p => p.Product).
            .Include(e => e.ProductImages.Where(p.ProductVariationId == e.ProductVariationId))
            .Select(p => new ProductSearch()
            {
                ProductId = p.ProductId,
                ProductVariationId = p.ProductVariationId,
                Name = p.Product.Name + " (" +  p.Name + ")",
                ImageUrl =  p.ProductImages.Any() ? p.ProductImages.First().ImageUrl : "PARENT IMAGE NEEDED HERE"
            }).ToListAsync();
            var productSearch = products.Union(productVariables).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();

            return productSearch;
```

This code runs fine and produces my list as intended, apart from where I have the string "PARENT IMAGE NEEDED HERE".

I did ask a similar question to this before (which was answered) but that was to create a list of products, including their variables (if any) whereas this list is different in that it does not include any collections of any kind.

Many thanks in advance, as usual.

Comment: Didnt you forget the lambda left side here: `.Include(e => e.ProductImages.Where(p.ProductVariationId == e.ProductVariationId))`? It should be with `p=>`

Comment: Could you post your classes? Queries is totally wrong and I cannot reverse engineer your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You only need to use .Include(x => x.SomeProperty) when you're letting EF construct the entities, not when you're selecting a NEW object. EF will automatically interpret your select and wire in the nested property data.

Example when you need to include so that product.ProductImages is populated:

```
var p = _context.Product
    // Without this include, the products in the return list will all have null
    // ProductImages property.
    .Include(p => p.ProductImages) 
    .ToList(); // A list of products WITH their ProductImages property populated.
```

Example when you don't need to use include (derived object / anonymous object) (obviously untested against your model):

```
var p = _context.Product
    .Select(p => new { // This could be a defined object too such as ProductSearch...
        p.Id,
        p.Name,
        MyDirectImages = p.ProductImages
            // You don't need to filter to this products images because the 
            // ProductImages navigation property is ALREADY only images for this product.
            .Where(i => i.IsDefault && p.ProductVariationId == null)
            .ToList(), // OK, could be .FirstOrDefault() as well if only expecting one.
        MyVariations = p.ProductVariations
            .Select(v => new {
                v.Id,
                v.Name,
                // Once again, the VariationImages (I'm guessing the name...) navigation
                // property is already only images for this variation.
                ImageUrl = v.VariationImages.Where(x => x.IsDefault).FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl
            }).ToList();

    })
    .ToList(); // A list of information about products
```

2. Without addressing the other superfluous includes, you can do this for your specific question:

Replace

```
ImageUrl = p.ProductImages.Any() ? p.ProductImages.First().ImageUrl : "PARENT IMAGE NEEDED HERE"
```

with

```
ImageUrl = p.ProductImages.Any() ? p.ProductImages.First().ImageUrl : p.Product.ProductImages.Where(x => x.IsDefault && x.ProductVariationId == null).FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl
```